# Migrating Exchange 2007 - 2010. Can't see address lists?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2007, exchange-migration

Migrating from Exchange 2007 to 2010.

Creating a mailbox on the 2007 server, and then moving the mailbox to the 2010 server, the user can see all of the address lists just fine.

Creating a mailbox on the 2010 server, the user can not see any address lists.

Why can't users set up on the 2010 server see any of the address lists (even though I can see them on the server).

I did move some of the Offline Address Book generation to the new server, but this seems to have done nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check the properties of the database where the user is located, adjust the path/server to the offline address book.

Comment: Trying variations, nothing so far....

It's peculiar that it works for users that are moved to the database, but not users created in the database.